# How to select values spanning across 3 columns in Excel?

Tags: excel

```
column 1   |  column 2  |  column 3   |   column 4(need result like below)

Oscar.won? |  Movies1   |  Movies2    |Oscar Won Movies Of Column 3

0            Godzilla    SPIDERMAN 3      Avatar
0            Spectre     Constantine      LOTR  
1            Avatar      Skyfall          Slumdog.M
1            Slumdog.M   Avatar
0            Hercules    LOTR
1            LOTR        Superbad
1         Some film     Slumdog.M
0         Some film     Some film
1         Some film     Some film
```

This table is in Excel 2016.Column 1 and 2 are related and has about 1 million rows.It has all the Oscar nominated films from 1927-2016. The value 1 in column 1 specifies that the corresponding film in column 2 has won an Oscar and 0 means it hasn't. column 3 has 5000 rows,is unrelated to columns 1 and 2. It has a mix of films which are all in column 2. 
Now,here is my question. I want to select the Oscar won movies of column 3. So basically I need to find all the column 3 films in column 2, then select only the ones which has won an Oscar and tabulate column 4.

Comment: Complete column 4 using a `index/match` or `Vlookup`.

Comment: Not exactly sure how your data is laid out, but you could maybe highlight columns 2 and 3 and add conditional formatting that would highlight duplicate values.  The duplicates would be the Oscar won movies.  Then, filter by color on column 2... will that work?  Or, just use a lookup function.

Comment: it will highlight the values that are common in 1 and 2 yes. But it will not specifically select the oscar won movies will it?..Thanks

Comment: sorry was editing..please see

Answer (score 0):

Use a V-lookup (=vlookup())
You can use that to look vertically through column 2 for a given movie name (from col 3) and find the value of col 1 for that movie name.

you'll need to put the movie titles in the first column though, and the Oscar indicator variable in the second column like pictured in this link: [Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGUY2.png)

Comment: but if i do it i will need to look up by typing each movie name and find the corresponding value isnt it? Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer with a little more detail. You won't have to type each movie name if you use a relative cell reference (notice the blue text "E3" in the formula bar, and the corresponding blue box underneath "Smaller list"

Answer (score -1):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$10,C2)>0,INDEX($B$2:$B$10,MATCH(C2,$B$2:$B$10,0)),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To get the unique list use this array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$10,MATCH(1,(COUNTIFS(B:B,$C$2:$C$10,A:A,1)>0)*(COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$C$2:$C$10)=0),0)),"")
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

---

Or this formula that does not require the CSE entry:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$10)/(COUNTIFS(A:A,1,B:B,$C$2:$C$10)>0),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Comment: try the second formula instead.  On the first you need to enter the formula in the formula bar and hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter while still in edit mode.  @NithinNampoothiry

Comment: tried that.soon as i press enter nothing happens and when i select that cell the formulae is displayed but nothing happens.

Comment: That means your data is not exactly the same.  There are spaces or other unprintable characters that make it so there are not exact matches.  Both formulas work on the data provided.  Look to the data. Find two that look like they should match then use EXACT on both cells.  It will return TRUE or FALSE if they match or not.

Comment: What excel are you using? @NithinNampoothiry

Comment: column 2 has a million rows and column 3 has 5000. but every oscar won film in column 3 is in column 2.Really appreciate your time mate

Comment: using Excel2016

Comment: 1 million rows?!! it may take some time to do the search then. Other than that I can't tell why it does not work for you.